# How to transform dwr callbacks into rest fetch with promises?

Tags: javascript, callback

this is the old code with a DWR invocation into a callback that I want to transform:

```
BpmAjaxControllerDwr.getEvents(businessUnit, objectTypeId, {
        callback : function(objectList) {
            eventSelectView.render(objectList);
        }
```

And this is what I have already working. The parameters from before are now url parameters and it just gets a json from the rest API:

```
fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(objectList => new Promise((resolve, reject) => eventSelectView.render(objectList)));
```

But I am suspicious:

If I add a resolve() invocation after the render call inside the promise, it also works.

If I remove the (resolve, reject) arrow function wrapper, it also works (the render function fills a select with some options), but it shows an error in the console: "promise resolver undefined is not a function"

So even if its working I don't think I'm using the Promises API correctly.

Any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Gonzalo

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(objectList => eventSelectView.render(objectList));
```

Comment: Yes. No reason to use `new Promise` here at all.

Comment: Btw, you'll probably want to [check whether the `response` is `.ok`](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/) before getting the `.json()`